# Mongoose giving duplicate key error when using reference

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am getting duplicate key error when I am using reference in my schema. I am keeping my user refence in post model. but a user can have multiple post. but mongoose not allowing to a user to create more than one post. It is definitely every post has to be different _id (key). but why it asking to every user in post have to be different key(_id)?

"error": {
"index": 0,
"code": 11000,
"keyPattern": {
"user._id": 1
},
"keyValue": {
"user._id": "63442c65caddd857cd8e5e00"
}
}

Comment: Can you post your Schema here? Also the code where you are creating the new entry?

Comment: you might have added the strict **unique : true** conditions to post schema because of which this issue is raising...

Comment: share your schema file once here.